# Angularjs UI modal resolve not working. ui.bootstrap.model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

User clicks on videoClick

```html
<div ng-repeat="list in lists" ng-click="videoClick(list.src)">
  {{list.src}}
</div>
```

This works and following executes.

```js
 $scope.videoClick = function(val) {
   $log.info('received.');
   var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
     size: 'lg',
     templateUrl: '/views/video_modal.html',
     animation: true,
     backdrop: false,
     controller: 'VideoController',
     resolve: {
       videoPath: function() {
         return val;
       }
     }
   });
 };
```

Now i am trying to get the value of 'videoPath' but i am getting an error.

**Inside 'VideoController'**

```js
angular
  .module('tss.application')
  .controller('VideoController', function(videoPath) {
    "use strict";
  });
```

*

Any idea why i am not able to get the value of 'videoPath' inside 'VideoController' ?

*

Comment: What's your error ?

Comment: And can you try `resolve: {videoPath: val}`

Comment: angular.js:13424 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: videoPathProvider <- videoPath <- VideoController

Comment: what is videoPath? if the is a directive, controller, service is it registered in the same module as "tss.aplication"?

Comment: Don't you have another function already called videoPath ?

Comment: no. Actually it should work, dont know why its not working. Anyway, i have alternate method by which i have added the parameter to $scopeRoot and retrieved it in 'VideoController'. This approach works fine. Still not sure why the earlier is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
angular
  .module('tss.application')
  .controller('VideoController',['videoPath',function(videoPath) {
    "use strict";
  }]);
```

Comment: Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: videoPathProvider <- videoPath <- VideoController